# How to execute a wildcard WHERE clause against a SELECTed ARRAY column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery

I have the following SQL.  I'm trying to limit results to only those with any label (in a list of labels) that matches a particular term.  This SQL is simplified -- there are many more columns and tables -- but hopefully this will illustrate the problem I'm having.

```sql
SELECT 
  account_id
  , ARRAY( SELECT(label_name || '::' || label_group) AS label
           FROM labels ) AS label_list

FROM accounts

WHERE
  account_id = 1

AND 
  '%sale%' ILIKE ANY (label_list)
```

In this example, I only want rows that have the term "sale" anywhere in the 'label_name::lable_group' that appears in each row's list of labels.  To further explain, I would like any rows that have any label such as "saleorder::presales".

So, of course, when I run the above query, I get this:

```
ERROR:  column "label_list" does not exist
```

I learned on StackOverflow why that doesn't work, and I understand that.

So then I tried copy/pasting the subquery into my predicate:

```sql
AND
'%sale%' ILIKE ANY (SELECT(label_name || '::' || label_group)
                    FROM labels)
```

and I get no errors, but also no matches even though there is a "saleorder::presales" label.

Interestingly, though, when I type a literal (non-wildcard) label_name::label_group value such as:

```sql
AND
'saleorder::presales' ILIKE ANY (SELECT(label_name || '::' || label_group)
                                 FROM labels)
```

I get a match, as if ILIKE were behaving like = instead.

I need to be able to search this type of column for wildcard values and just can't figure it out after quite a few hours of trying different things.  I'd be grateful for any insight.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain your problem.  A SQL Fiddle is also helpful.

Comment: Are you sure you want use `ARRAY`? In your case that create an array of size 1 with a string with all the labels inside

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is on the wrong side of ILIKE. You have essentially `'%bar%' ilike 'foobar'`, while you need `'foobar' ilike '%bar%'`. I am unaware of an elegant way of swapping them around in your case...

The best thing I can come up with is :

```
select * from(
SELECT 
  account_id
  , ARRAY( SELECT(label_name || '::' || label_group) AS label
           FROM labels ) AS label_list
FROM accounts
WHERE
  account_id = 1
)X
where exists(select * from unnest(label_list) U where U ilike '%sale%')
```

Comment: To swap them around you need to define a custom operator that calls a wrapper SQL function that in turn does the `ilike`, then use that operator as a "reverse ilike" in the `ANY` term. A bit cumbersome.